# ERR ! Failed at the start script

Tags: npm, webpack-dev-server

I have an issue when I try to start a project. Here they are:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

This project may need Linux or Mac to work well but I don't have any of them. I ran `npm i` at the beginning

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: How did you start the server ? Which command ?

Comment: In fact i have tried many things but i don't really know how to start it...

Comment: Did you try `npm run start`?

Comment: Yes and that gave me the error on the first picture

Comment: Those scripts weren't set up for Windows. Try git bash or WSL.

Comment: Can you tell me how to use these tools ?

Comment: I can't find a solution so far.... Has anyone a solution ? thank you !